# running axis2 as a part of my project

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, integration, apache-axis

The situation:

Now, I can create .aar file according to my wsld file. If I placed this .aar file into a specific folder (%AXIS2_HOME%/repository/services) I can call the methods of the the skeleton file (generated by wsdl2java) by a web browser. (It is explained in their starter guide)

However, I have a custom framework and everything is working as a part of this framework. Therefore,  I want to start axis2 as a part of this framework. is it possible? Another word to say, I want to make it a bridge between my framework and the outer world.

If it is not possible, how can I establish a connection between my framework and skeleton?

Note: I am new to software development concept and this might be very trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a while, i found the solution. Actually it is extremely easy.

Just include the required axis2 libraries under your project. 
And modify SimpleAxis2Server.java for your own preferences... :D
Thats it.

I love the apache software foundation..